# magento 2 Use in Layered Navigation option showing backend

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am using **`Magento ver. 2.1.4`** in Backend I add Attribute it not showing in front end

In Backend **`Use in Layered Navigation`** option also not showing in backend

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: which type is keep for your custom attribute? Its dropdown,Visual swatch and multiple select only contains Use in layered navigation field so first check for `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` value of your attribute.

Comment: I check price attribute there also not showing this

Comment: I set Dropdown to my Custom attribute

Comment: please show your screenshot of catalog Input Type for store owner page.

Comment: Check my Updated question

Comment: do you have added product with these attributes?

Comment: Yes i added....

Comment: Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Magento_LayeredNavigation set to Yes?

Comment: It's already Enable only

Comment: Please atash a print screen from frontend with category page, do you have everything else attribute in fronted ?

Comment: You deleted cache after added attribute and set it on product ?

Comment: I tried everything delete cache folder reindex but no luck